# How would i hide the first ol li number but still show the item text?

Tags: html-lists, hide

In my ol below, i want the first li to hide its number, and then the second li to start at 1. Is this possible?

1. **Heading Herewith no number - so hide the 1.**
2. so this li would be number 1.
3. this would be number 2.
4. etc
5. etc

Answer (score 4):

Another Option (See http://jsfiddle.net/ECjLs/)

HTML

```
<ol class="my-awesome-counter">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li value="1">Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
li:first-child {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the number using CSS and use the "value" attribute to set the ordinal value of an entry and any subsequent entry.

```
<ol>
    <li style="font-weight: bold; list-style-type:none">Heading Herewith no number - so hide the 1.</li>
    <li value="1">so this li would be number 1.</li>
    <li>this would be number 2.</li>
    <li>etc</li>
    <li>etc</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try css counters: http://jsfiddle.net/QKgMq/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>true first</li>
    <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul>li:nth-child(2) {
    counter-reset: term;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:first-child:before{
   content:'';
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: term;
    content: counter(term);
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

Item one

Item two

Item three

Item four

simply using css you can do the following to hide the first number from the ol list:

CSS:
    ol li:first-child {
        list-style:none;
    }

Result :
   Item One
2  Item two
3  Item three
4  Item four